# Which way is more reliable to delete a node in the Binary Search Tree from two different ways?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Which one is Correct? While Removing node with two children, we have to pick the smallest node in the Right subtree? or the biggest Node in the Left Subtree?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292661/how-to-delete-a-node-with-2-children-nodes-in-a-binary-search-tree

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. Which one you use is up to you.