# Deleting a node in a binary tree having children

Tags: data-structures

If we have to delete a node from a binary tree, how should we handle the children of the node being deleted. E.g. in this tree:

```
    100
   /
  10 
 /  \
5    20
```

where `100` is the root node, `10` is left child of `100`, `5` is left child of `10` and `20` is right child of `10`. So after deleting `10`, what will happen to `5` and `20`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a node with 2 children nodes in a binary search tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292661/how-to-delete-a-node-with-2-children-nodes-in-a-binary-search-tree)

Answer (score 0):

It is your choice if what should you do after deleting.You would probably want to move one of the child upward on some so certain criteria. Either of of Child will take place of parent.

1. [delete node in Binary Search Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/).
2. [delete node in AVL](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-2-deletion/).
3. [Heapify in Heapsort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/).
4. And more.

**So it is always a choice you have to take to solve for objective.**